# TaxID from Gene Accession Number: Efetch

Tags: bioinformatics, blast, ncbi

I have conducted a blast search on some ASV's from bat guano, and I would like to try and assign taxonomy to each feature that had a hit, if it did.

There is a lot online about using efetch, but there wasn't a clear consensus on a tool that would allow me to go from accession # -> taxid # -> taxonomic lineage

I found some scripts on github, but unfortunately they have been popping up with errors! I thought to try and use what I do know to find a solution (but I am at a pretty introductory level).

I am currently trying to made a python notebook to allow me to do this, and utilize the subprocess package in python to run what will be one line of commandline code (where I will be using efetch).

I've found a text file with taxid's from NCBI, and the taxonomic lineage associated with it. My aim is once I have added the taxid to my dataframe (which my blast output acts as), I can do a simple merge with pandas to get the associated taxonomy.

I'm running into trouble with this first step!

The code I've been trying to run this far is

```
def givetaxid(accession_only_file):
        df = pd.read_csv(accession_only_file, delimiter="\t")
        taxid_list = [] #we're going to append the taxid for each accession number into this list, then add it as a column in our dataframe
        accession_ids =df["accession"].tolist()

        for ids in accession_ids:
            taxid_list.append(subprocess.call(["efetch", "-db", "nucccore", "-a", ids, "-format", "docsum", "|", "xtract", "-pattern", "DocumentSummary", "-element", "TaxId"],shell=True))

        df['TaxId'] = np.array(taxid_list)


        return taxid_list
```

My output is:

```
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
```

I'm a little new to all this, but it seems that it fails to take anything. When I separately try to run the efetch command

```
$ efetch -d nuccore -a JQ663175.1JQ663175.1 -f 
Could not open the index file named:  entrynam.idx
```

This is what I seem to be getting! I've tried looking through for a similar error, but I can't seem to grab anything from stackoverflow, or biostars.

If there's anyone more familiar, I was wondering if they could help provide some clarity? Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you running BLAST locally? If so, you can get tabular output containing subject taxid using `-outfmt "6 staxid"` (plus any other column identifiers that you want to include). See _e.g._ [this example](https://www.biostars.org/p/355304/).

Comment: I was running it remotely! I abandoned trying to use efetch, and managed to find a way to assign taxonomic lineage without it!

That is a very handy heads up, though! Thank you :)